# Как вернуть ArrayCollection вместо PersistentCollection, после flush?

Tags: коллекции, symfony, orm, doctrine

Я создал класс 1 в 1 как **ArrayCollection**, со свойством `protected $elements`(чтобы наследовать и переопределять), назвал свою коллекцию **DocumentsCollection**, в ней добавил дополнительные методы для работы с объектом. Но после того как я сохраняю объект в базу `$em->persist($person);` и `$em->flush();`, у меня в объекте `$person` свойство типа **DocumentsCollection** возвращается с типом **PersistentCollection**. Но мне нужно чтобы вернулась моя коллекция с типом **DocumentsCollection** для обращения к методам данного объекта, я конечно могу каждый раз делать `$person->getDocuments()->unwrap()`, чтобы вернуть **DocumentsCollection**, но в моем случае это костыль, хотелось бы от него избавиться. Нужна помощь и подсказки, кто сталкивался, как после `$em->persist($person);` и `$em->flush();` вернуть сразу мою коллекцию, а не **PersistentCollection**.

Comment: Никак, наверное. Возвращаемые значения зашиты в доктрине. Можно сделать геттер/сеттер прослойку в модели, которая будет возвращать DocumentCollection, созданный из Collection и наоборот сеттер на вход будет принимать DocumentCollection и преобразовывать его в приватный ArrayCollection

Comment: Как понимаю, что-то вроде того что писал, у меня сейчас это $person->setDocuments($person->getDocuments()->unwrap());? Но мб, как-то в репозитории можно переопределить что-то? Я подобное делал с методом matching(Criteria $ctireria), который возвращал собственную LazyCriteriaCollection и уже там преобразовывал в нужный мне объект.

Comment: вот тут описывают ситуацию https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691943/custom-collection-in-doctrine2